# Do I need to create my own virtual ttys with n_gsm line discipline?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gsm

There are a few "how to" pages that give instructions on using n_gsm line discipline, including [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/n_gsm.txt) one, which comes from the tome of Linux kernel knowledge.  On that page, step 4 give instructions on how to create virtual serial ports, which I did when I first started using n_gsm.  However, I've noticed that when I enable n_gsm line dicipline with the following code:

```
int ldisc = N_GSM0710;
struct gsm_config gsm;
ioctl(_fd, TIOCSETD, &ldisc);
ioctl(_fd, GSMIOC_GETCONF, &gsm);
gsm.initiator = 1;
gsm.encapsulation = 0;
gsm.mru = 121;
gsm.mtu = 121;
ioctl(_fd, GSMIOC_SETCONF, &gsm);
```

A whole bunch of gsmtty's show up in /dev, (i.e. /dev/gsmtty[1-63]) and disappear when my program exits (clears n_gsm line discipline).

So is it necessary to create my own virtual serial ports or can I use these gsmtty* ports?  Also, I seem to recall reading that there is something special about /dev/gsmtty1, but I can't find the page.  Is there something special about gsmtty1?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't find help on Stack Overflow, then try the [Kernel Newbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/MailingList) mailing list. I often go to the group for help on some types of problems.